# How to pass data from a scrollview

Tags: android

I have a Scrollview, and inside the Scrollview is TextViews.

I want to pass all those textview data through intent to another Scrollview.

Comment: This is very vague. What is the data you need to send? How is it structured? Show what you have done

Comment: How are you looking to open another activity? With an intent?

Comment: your question is not clear . no one sends data to another activity by a scrollview . what is your code ???

Comment: ok so I have a scroll view will textview inside I want to pass the textview data to another activity inside the recieving scrollview

Comment: It does not matter if it's a ScrollView or not, you just send data to the activity you try to open.

Comment: So I don't have to refer to the scrollview I can just send the textview data and do you kno how to recieve it inside the scrollview

Comment: As stated Scrollview is not important. The Intent and how you put String data from the TextViews is. Please [edit] your question to include the code that you are working with. For more information, see about making a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

If you are opening the other activity with an intent, you can use 
`intentName.putExtra();`.

Comment: Add the way to recover the data ;) this could help him I think

Comment: Accept the answer?

Answer (score 0):

First u have to take that data from textview id from xml(no matter if it is scrollview.we collectivly called it xml file).
Follow the example

1.activity.xml:

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/one"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="30dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtname"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="textview1" />

    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

2.In your MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView txtname;
String name;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //to get the textview from xml
    txtname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtname);
    name = txtname.getText().toString();

    //to send this name u need to call intent
    Intent intent_data = new Intent(this, ActivityTwo.class);
    //by using pupExtra method we can send the data from one activity to another
    intent_data.putExtra("Name", name);
    startActivity(intent_data);
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks so I all I had to do is past the textview data what about the recieving activity

Comment: If u feel this is useful.please accept my answer and up vote.